# Accessing Json value by dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, json, variables, dynamic

Ok first thing json structure

```
[{
    "type": "button",
    "name": "Off",
    "tabname": "1",
    "image_file": "path\\Off.gif"
  }, {
    "type": "button",
    "name": "Off1",
    "tabname": "2",
    "image_file": "path\\Off1.gif",
    "image_file_1": "path\\On1.gif"
  }, {
    "type": "button",
    "name": "Off2",
    "tabname": "3",
    "image_file": "path\\Off2.gif",
    "image_file_1": "path\\On2.gif",
    "image_file_2": "path\\half.gif"
  }
]
```

image_file fields can have multiple entry (ie image_file, image_file_1, image_file_2 etc), how would I access that dynamically in a loop?

Current not working code (just the relavant stuff)

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
  var images = [];
  imageIndex = 1;
  continueLoop = true;
  while(continueLoop) {
    if(imageIndex == 1) {
      images.push(data[i].image_file);
    }
    else {
      var testVal = 'image_file_' + imageIndex;
      alert(data[i][testVal]);
      if(data[i][testVal] === undefined) {
        continueLoop = false;
      }
      else {
        images.push(data[i][testVal]);

      }
    }
    imageIndex++;
  }
});
```

the first iteration works fine (ie the `if (imageIndex == 1)`  bit), but the `else` clause alert I've put in to test the value always returns undefined

Any help would be sincerely appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can understand your code, you are getting all `image_file` properties, even those with numbers. [You can easily do it with this](http://jsfiddle.net/jA7XD/1/):

```
var images = [];

//iterate through the array
$.each(data, function (i, item) {

  //iterate through each property
  $.each(item, function (key, value) {

    //if the property starts with image_file, push into the array
    if (key.indexOf('image_file') === 0) images.push(value);
  });
});

console.log(images); // ["path\\Off.gif","path\\Off1.gif","path\\On1.gif","path\\Off2.gif","path\\On2.gif","path\\half.gif"]
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, even tho my issue was caused by simple oversight highlighted by jcsanyi, this is a much better method for me currently

Answer (score 2):

You're skipping `image_file_1`, and going directly from `image_file` to `image_file_2`

Try starting imageIndex at 0, and mapping 0 to `image_file`.

```
imageIndex = 0;
continueLoop = true;
while(continueLoop) {
  if(imageIndex == 0) {
    images.push(data[i].image_file);
  }
  // rest of your code unchanged
```

Comment: Yes, thank you glad it was just me being a dumbass, although ill be going with Joseph the dreamers code as it offers the most elegant solution for ny needs- thanks to all though

Answer (score 0):

The best option in this case would be to make the image_files an array in JSON.

```
[{
   ...
  }, {
    "type": "button",
    "name": "Off2",
    "tabname": "3",
    "image_files": ["path\\Off2.gif", "path\\On2.gif","path\\half.gif"]
  }
]
```

Then you could just iterate over those elegantly.

But since we all know the pain of having to work with someone else's JSON, the way I'd extract this data is the following:

```
images = []
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    imageIndex = 0
    while ( true ) {
        image = item["image_file" + ( imageIndex === 0 ? "" : "_" + imageIndex )]
        if ( typeof image === 'undefined' ) {
            break
        }
        images.push(image)
        imageIndex += 1
    }
})
```